# How to update dynamically a model in Django?

Tags: python, django, csv, numpy, django-models

I want to fill my django model from a csv. I upload the csv with numpy and then, since my model fields are called like the column headers of the csv, I would like to do something like this:

```
data=np.genfromtxt("file.csv", delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True)
columns = data.dtype.names
for i in range(len(data['id'])):
    for a in range(1, len(columns)): #1 
        p=MyModel.objects.filter(columns[a]=data[i][columns[a]])
            p.save()
```

Now, this is quite row, and it doesn't work because I can't pass that columns[a] instead of the field name.

I even tried something like `MyModel._meta_fields[a]=data[i][a].`

I have tens or even hundreds of fields, sometimes: isn't there an elegant solution that would me spare to write e long list of field names?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to create new instances of your model from each row of the data, use the `setattr` function to set the values:

```
data=np.genfromtxt("file.csv", delimiter=',', dtype=None, names=True)
columns = data.dtype.names
for i in range(len(data['id'])):
    p = MyModel()
    for a in range(1, len(columns)): #1
        if hasattr(p, columns[a]):
            setattr(p, columns[a], data[i][columns[a]])
        else:
            raise AttributeError("'MyModel' object has no attribute '{0}'".format(columns[a]))
    p.save()
```

Comment: Actually, I realised that if I use a wrong attribute I don't get the error that I would get if I do `p=MyModel.objects.filter(WRONG_ATTRIBUTE=whatever)`. Any way to get this error?

Comment: @foebu - Sure, just check for its existence with `hasattr` before setting it. I've updated the example.

Comment: In the end, since I wanted to raise an exception, I used the p._meta.get_field('wrong_attr'). Thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could consider constructing a dictionary of the arguments you want to pass, and then use `**` to supply the dictionary to the function as those arguments.

```
column_args_dict = {columns[a]: data[i][columns[a]]}
p = MyModel.objects.filter(**column_args_dict)
```

Comment: I'll try this too and update the comment.. now I got it work with the setattr. Thank you!